# Algorithmically find a formal grammar for a recursively enumerable formal language

Tags: formal-languages, computability, formal-grammars

The algorithmic problem is as follows.

The input is the source code of a program accepting an integer as input and outputting a finite binary sequence. This program defines a recursively enumerable formal language.

The output is a formal grammar generating this language.

How can we solve this problem?

Comment: How does the program define a language?  What do you mean by a grammar?  Do you mean by a context-free grammar?  an unrestricted grammar?  Do you have any reason to believe this problem is computable?  What's the context where you encountered it?

Comment: @D.W. It defines a language becase you can iterate through integers and get countably infinitely many strings. A formal grammar is defined here for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar. It is not necessarily context-free. I have no reasons to believe it is computable. I encountered this question by thinking about the ways one can define a recursively enumerable formal language (one way would be a grammar, the other would be a program).

Comment: There are known algorithms to convert a Turing machine to an equivalent unrestricted grammar. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrestricted_grammar#Equivalence_to_Turing_machines) gives a hint and a reference.

Comment: I encourage you to [edit] the question to include all of that information in the question.  We want questions to be self-contained, so people don't have to read the comments to understand what you are asking. I suggest you specify exactly which language is defined by the program (not just that it defines some language, as that requires us to guess which one you have in mind).